# Symfony - creating database dump in php

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am currently developing an backup system which is backuping database dump and media files.

I know that `php app/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql` will create database dump for me, but thats not what i need. I need to create database dump file exactly from php class so i can work with it (for example, to encode it).

How can i create database dump from class using symfony?

Comment: You want to get just empty schema of your database? This same what's created by command?

Comment: `$dump = shell_exec('php app/console etc...');`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use schema tool manually (example can be used in controller action):

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$schemaTool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($em);
$metadatas = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
$sqls = $schemaTool->getCreateSchemaSql($metadatas);
```